# Multicore Simulators supporting MPI

Tags: mpi, multicore, simulator

I am new to the parallel programming world. Are there any multicore simulators with proper documentation that support MPI?  Please let me know if so ..
Any other means to run MPI programs on different multicore architectures would also help.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Vivek

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? MPI is just a networking middleware. You don't need special support for it in an emulator. You can run MPI programs on almost any architecture, even on a single core CPU with time-division multitasking. Just `mpirun -n <# of proceses> program` and it will run, although slow, but it will run. Of course, having multicore CPU(s) in the system will allow MPI processes to be scheduled to different cores and the program as a whole will run faster.

Comment: I want to know the performance of the execution of MPI code by varying the number of cores and stuff.. Is that possible?

Comment: It might be possible but then you would also have to simulate the effects of network latency/bandwidth or shared memory performance. You might be better off making an analytical model.